# Songs don't download in iTunes

Tags: itunes

Songs no longer download to my iTunes. I click on the cloud with the down arrow and nothing happens. Why won't the songs download?

Comment: What mac are you using and what version of the system software?

Comment: iMac   OS X Yosemite 10.10.5   iTunes 12.8.1.3